# matlab error using m power

Tags: matlab

so if I run this function in matlab

```
sim1(row,1:512)= ((image(row,1:512,1)-a(1,1)));
```

it runs fine. now if I modify it to take the square like this

```
sim1(row,1:512)= ((image(row,1:512,1)-a(1,1)))^2;
```

it gives me the error, error using ==> mpower
matrix dimensions must agree. Why is this giving me the error, I can do this element by element but I have a lot of data and it will take forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want to do an element by element power which is .^2 not ^2

That is, change to

```
sim1(row,1:512)= ((image(row,1:512,1)-a(1,1))).^2;
```